# Print full signature of a method from a MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, reflection

Is there any existing functionality in the .NET [BCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)#Base_Class_Library) to print the full signature of a method at runtime (like what you'd see in the Visual Studio ObjectBrowser - including parameter names) using information available from MethodInfo?

So for example, if you look up String.Compare() one of the overloads would print as:

```
public static int Compare(string strA, int indexA, string strB, int indexB, int length, bool ignoreCase, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
```

Note the presence of the complete signature with all access and scope qualifiers as well as a complete list of parameters including names. This is what I'm looking for. I could write my own method, but I would rather use an existing implementation if possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a built in method that would do that. Your best be would be to create your own signature by investigating the MethodInfo class

**EDIT: I just did this**

```
 MethodBase mi = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
 mi.ToString();
```

and you get

> Void Main(System.String[])

This might not be what you're looking for, but it's close.

How about this

```
public static class MethodInfoExtension
{
    public static string MethodSignature(this MethodInfo mi)
    {
        String[] param = mi.GetParameters()
                           .Select(p => String.Format("{0} {1}",p.ParameterType.Name,p.Name))
                           .ToArray();

        string signature = String.Format("{0} {1}({2})", mi.ReturnType.Name, mi.Name, String.Join(",", param));

        return signature;
    }
}

var methods = typeof(string).GetMethods().Where( x => x.Name.Equals("Compare"));
    
foreach(MethodInfo item in methods)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.MethodSignature());
}
```

This is the result

> Int32 Compare(String strA,Int32
> indexA,String strB,Int32 indexB,Int32
> length,StringComparison
> comparisonType)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, my use case does require the parameter names to the method, which MethodInfo.ToString() doesn't emit.

Answer (score 36):

#### Update 3/22/2018

I've rewritten the code, added a few tests, and [uploaded it to GitHub](https://github.com/kellyelton/Eltons.ReflectionKit)

It's also available through nuget

Eltons.ReflectionKit  [image: NuGet]

#### Answer

```
using System.Text;

namespace System.Reflection
{
    public static class MethodInfoExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Return the method signature as a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method">The Method</param>
        /// <param name="callable">Return as an callable string(public void a(string b) would return a(b))</param>
        /// <returns>Method signature</returns>
        public static string GetSignature(this MethodInfo method, bool callable = false)
        {
            var firstParam = true;
            var sigBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (callable == false)
            {
                if (method.IsPublic)
                    sigBuilder.Append("public ");
                else if (method.IsPrivate)
                    sigBuilder.Append("private ");
                else if (method.IsAssembly)
                    sigBuilder.Append("internal ");
                if (method.IsFamily)
                    sigBuilder.Append("protected ");
                if (method.IsStatic)
                    sigBuilder.Append("static ");
                sigBuilder.Append(TypeName(method.ReturnType));
                sigBuilder.Append(' ');
            }
            sigBuilder.Append(method.Name);

            // Add method generics
            if(method.IsGenericMethod)
            {
                sigBuilder.Append("<");
                foreach(var g in method.GetGenericArguments())
                {
                    if (firstParam)
                        firstParam = false;
                    else
                        sigBuilder.Append(", ");
                    sigBuilder.Append(TypeName(g));
                }
                sigBuilder.Append(">");
            }
            sigBuilder.Append("(");
            firstParam = true;
            var secondParam = false;
            foreach (var param in method.GetParameters())
            {
                if (firstParam)
                {
                    firstParam = false;
                    if (method.IsDefined(typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute), false))
                    {
                        if (callable)
                        {
                            secondParam = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        sigBuilder.Append("this ");
                    }
                }
                else if (secondParam == true)
                    secondParam = false;
                else
                    sigBuilder.Append(", ");
                if (param.ParameterType.IsByRef)
                    sigBuilder.Append("ref ");
                else if (param.IsOut)
                    sigBuilder.Append("out ");
                if (!callable)
                {
                    sigBuilder.Append(TypeName(param.ParameterType));
                    sigBuilder.Append(' ');
                }
                sigBuilder.Append(param.Name);
            }
            sigBuilder.Append(")");
            return sigBuilder.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get full type name with full namespace names
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">Type. May be generic or nullable</param>
        /// <returns>Full type name, fully qualified namespaces</returns>
        public static string TypeName(Type type)
        {
            var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
            if (nullableType != null)
                return nullableType.Name + "?";

            if (!(type.IsGenericType && type.Name.Contains('`')))
                switch (type.Name)
                {
                    case "String": return "string";
                    case "Int32": return "int";
                    case "Decimal": return "decimal";
                    case "Object": return "object";
                    case "Void": return "void";
                    default:
                        {
                            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(type.FullName) ? type.Name : type.FullName;
                        }
                }

            var sb = new StringBuilder(type.Name.Substring(0,
            type.Name.IndexOf('`'))
            );
            sb.Append('<');
            var first = true;
            foreach (var t in type.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                if (!first)
                    sb.Append(',');
                sb.Append(TypeName(t));
                first = false;
            }
            sb.Append('>');
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

This handles practically everything, including extension methods. Got a head start from http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/getting-correct-method-signature-t3660896.html.

I used it in tandum with a T4 template to generate overloads for all the `Queryable` and `Enumerable` Linq extension methods.

Comment: Thanks for this... saved me a lot of time. I built it out a little more to handle param arrays, optional parameters and generic constraints, as well as properties. Still not 100% complete but figured I'd pass it along. https://gist.github.com/4476307

Comment: @jamietre Nice, I forked it, I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: thanks, thats work for Generik methods and Generic parameters too

Comment: @JamieTreworgy That is indeed very nice! Have you perhaps thought about writing some Unit Tests for it and publishing on Nuget?

Comment: I would, but I am already seriously delinquent on keeping up with my existing open source projects :)

Comment: Yeah I thought about it as well, but am in the same boat.

Comment: Works great! I made a small edit to the code - for nested types under generic types, `IsGenericType` is true, but the name does not contain the backwards ' character, which causes an exception in the Substring call.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the GetParameters() method on MethodBase. That will give you the info about the parameters including the name of the parameter. I don't believe a pre-existing method exists to print out the name but using the ParameterInfo[] to build that should be trivial.

How about this:

```
public string GetSignature(MethodInfo mi)
{
  if(mi == null)
    return "";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  if(mi.IsPrivate)
    sb.Append("private ");
  else if(mi.IsPublic)
    sb.Append("public ");
  if(mi.IsAbstract)
    sb.Append("abstract ");
  if(mi.IsStatic)
    sb.Append("static ");
  if(mi.IsVirtual)
    sb.Append("virtual ");

  sb.Append(mi.ReturnType.Name + " ");

  sb.Append(mi.Name + "(");

  String[] param = mi.GetParameters()
    .Select(p => String.Format(
              "{0} {1}",p.ParameterType.Name,p.Name))
                          .ToArray();


  sb.Append(String.Join(", ",param));

  sb.Append(")");

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the method has a parameter, `ParameterInfo.Member.ToString()` will output what you want. If not, it's pretty easy to create the signature. This method will return what you want:

```
public string PrintSignature(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
    return parameters.Length > 0 ? parameters[0].Member.ToString() : $"{methodInfo.ReturnType.ToString()} {methodInfo.Name}()";
}
```

If you want access qualifiers as well:

```
public string GetSignatureSansModifiers(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
    return parameters.Length > 0 ? parameters[0].Member.ToString() : $"{methodInfo.ReturnType.ToString()} {methodInfo.Name}()";
}

public string PrintSignature(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (methodInfo.IsPrivate)
        sb.Append("private ");
    else if (methodInfo.IsPublic)
        sb.Append("public ");
    if (methodInfo.IsAbstract)
        sb.Append("abstract ");
    if (methodInfo.IsStatic)
        sb.Append("static ");
    if (methodInfo.IsVirtual)
        sb.Append("virtual ");
    sb.Append(GetSignatureSansModifiers(methodInfo));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```